# Generar un menu html con un array en php

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo este array:

```
 <?php
    $MENU = array();

    $MENU["ESCRITORIO"] = array
        (
        'emparentar' => true, // emparentar == true ? muestra en el nivel superior menu : no lo muestra en el nivel superior
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Escritorio',
        'link' => 'public/escritorio',
        'sub_modules' => array()   // si esta vacia es que no tiene sub menus
    );

    $MENU["ODONTOLOGIA"] = array
        (
        'emparentar' => true,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Odontologia',
        'link' => 'public/shop',
        'sub_modules' => array('PACIENTES', 'CONSULTAS', 'RECIPES', 'CITAS') // PACIENTES, CONSULTAS , RECIPES, CITAS son un sub menu de odontologia y estan configurados mas abajo
    );
    $MENU['PACIENTES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => false,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Pacientes',
        'link' => 'public/odontologia/pacientes',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );

    $MENU['CONSULTAS'] = array(
        'emparentar' => false,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Consultas',
        'link' => 'public/odontologia/consultas',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );

    $MENU['RECIPES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => false,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Recipes',
        'link' => 'public/odontologia/recipes',
        'sub_modules' => array('INDICACIONES')
    );
    $MENU['INDICACIONES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => false,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Indicaciones',
        'link' => 'public/odontologia/recipes/indicaciones',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
    $MENU['CITAS'] = array(
        'emparentar' => false,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Citas',
        'link' => 'public/odontologia/citas',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
    $MENU['ORTODONCIA'] = array
        (
        'emparentar' => TRUE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Ortodoncia',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia',
        'sub_modules' => array('ORTPACIENTES', 'ORTCONSULTA', 'ORTRECIPE', 'ORTCITAS')
    );

    $MENU['ORTPACIENTES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => FALSE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Pacientes',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia/pacientes',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );

    $MENU['ORTCONSULTA'] = array(
        'emparentar' => FALSE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Consultas',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia/consultas',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );

    $MENU['ORTRECIPE'] = array(
        'emparentar' => FALSE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Recipes',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia/recipes',
        'sub_modules' => array('ORTINDICACIONES')
    );
    $MENU['ORTINDICACIONES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => FALSE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Indicaciones',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia/indicaciones',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );

    $MENU['ORTCITAS'] = array(
        'emparentar' => FALSE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Citas',
        'link' => 'public/ortodoncia/citas',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
    $MENU['CONFIGURACION'] = array(
        'emparentar' => TRUE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Configuracion',
        'link' => 'public/configuracion',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
    $MENU['REPORTES'] = array(
        'emparentar' => TRUE,
        'abilitado' => TRUE,
        'text' => 'Reportes',
        'link' => 'public/Reportes',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
    $MENU['SALIR'] = array(
        'emparentar' => TRUE,
        'abilitado' => true,
        'text' => 'Salir',
        'link' => 'public/salir',
        'sub_modules' => array()
    );
```

ademas para recorrer dicho array tengo este codigo

```
 function show_menu($MENU, $subIndex = false) {

        $menu_string = '<ul>';


        if (!$subIndex) {
            foreach ($MENU as $item) {
                if ($item['abilitado'] && $item['emparentar']) {
                    $_subString = "";
                    if (!empty($item['sub_modules'])) {
                        foreach ($item['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                            $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                        }
                    }
                    $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $item['link'] . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($MENU[$subIndex]['abilitado'] && !$MENU[$subIndex]['emparentar']) {
                $_subString = "";
                if (!empty($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'])) {
                    foreach ($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                        $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                    }
                }
                $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $MENU[$subIndex]['link'] . '">' . $MENU[$subIndex]['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
            }
        }

        return $menu_string . '</ul>';
    }
```

El error que tengo es que al momento de generar el menu en la vista se genera bien pero cuando voy a inspecccionar el elemento en el navegador aparece de la siguiente manera:

```
 <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="public/escritorio">Escritorio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="public/shop">Odontologia</a>
            <!-- Aqui comienza el error -->
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/odontologia/pacientes">Pacientes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/odontologia/consultas">Consultas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/odontologia/recipes">Recipes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="public/odontologia/recipes/indicaciones">Indicaciones</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/odontologia/citas">Citas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="public/ortodoncia">Ortodoncia</a>
            <!--Aqui se repite el error-->
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/ortodoncia/pacientes">Pacientes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/ortodoncia/consultas">Consultas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/ortodoncia/recipes">Recipes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="public/ortodoncia/indicaciones">Indicaciones</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="public/ortodoncia/citas">Citas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="public/configuracion">Configuracion</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="public/Reportes">Reportes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="public/salir">Salir</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

como pudieron ver al momento de generar un sub menu las de etiqueta < ul > se repite por cada item del submenu y deberia ser una etiqueta un por cada grupo de item de un submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que se llame a la función `show_menu()` se incluye el `<ul></ul>` sin ninguna condición, voy a proponer una solución rápida, basado en el código existente, aunque hay mejores maneras de hacerlo (lo cual necesitaría tal vez reescribir un poco la función).

También asumo que cuando se llama la función para generar el menú, el valor del parámetro de entrada `$subIndex` es false.

```
function show_menu($MENU, $subIndex = false) {

    if (!$subIndex) {

        $menu_string = '';
        // agregamos <ul> solo en el primer nivel
        $menu_string = '<ul>';

        foreach ($MENU as $item) {
            if ($item['abilitado'] && $item['emparentar']) { // debería ser 'habilitado'
                $_subString = "";
                if (!empty($item['sub_modules'])) {

                    // agregamos <ul></ul> alrededor del iterador para los elementos que tienen $subIndex
                    $_subString .= '<ul>';
                    foreach ($item['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                        $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                    }
                    $_subString .= '</ul>';

                }
                $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $item['link'] . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
            }
        }

        // de nuevo cerramos solo en el primer nivel
        $menu_string = $menu_string . '</ul>';

    } else {
        if ($MENU[$subIndex]['abilitado'] && !$MENU[$subIndex]['emparentar']) {
            $_subString = "";
            if (!empty($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'])) {
                foreach ($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                    $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                }
            }
            $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $MENU[$subIndex]['link'] . '">' . $MENU[$subIndex]['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
        }
    }

    return $menu_string;
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias de verdad por tu pronta respuesta y jajajajaja 'abilitado' ese horror ortográfico jajajaja y es en serio ese era el error y si tienes razón con respecto a la función se puede mejorar es solo que aún estoy incursionando en esto de php ha y disculpa pero sabes ahora el menú solo es de dos niveles y antes de 3 sé que estoy a lo mejor pidiendo demasiado pero me darías otra ayudita con respecto a eso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ha por cierto tuve que sacar la variable  $menu_string de la condición 
if (!$subIndex) para que no saliera el mensaje de que la variable no esta definida.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está la función 100% funcional:

```
 function show_menu($MENU, $subIndex = false) {
        $menu_string = '';
        if (!$subIndex) {


            // agregamos <ul> solo en el primer nivel
            $menu_string = '<ul>';

            foreach ($MENU as $item) {
                if ($item['habilitado'] && $item['emparentar']) { // debería ser 'hhabilitado'
                    $_subString = "";
                    if (!empty($item['sub_modules'])) {

                        // agregamos <ul></ul> alrededor del iterador para los elementos que tienen $subIndex
                        $_subString .= '<ul>';
                        foreach ($item['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                            $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                        }
                        $_subString .= '</ul>';
                    }
                    $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $item['link'] . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
                }
            }

            // de nuevo cerramos solo en el primer nivel
            $menu_string = $menu_string . '</ul>';
        } else {
            if ($MENU[$subIndex]['habilitado'] && !$MENU[$subIndex]['emparentar']) {
                $_subString = "";

                if (!empty($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'])) {
                    //agregamos <ul> para los submenus de los submenus jajaja
                    $_subString.='<ul>';
                    foreach ($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'] as $sub) {
                        $_subString .= show_menu($MENU, $sub);
                    }
                    $_subString.='</ul>';
                }
                $menu_string .= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $MENU[$subIndex]['link'] . '">' . $MENU[$subIndex]['text'] . '</a>' . $_subString . '</li>';
            }
        }

        return $menu_string;
    }
```

Ya corregí el error que te mencioné de que solo podía ser de 2 niveles.